# Retrieving simple data from firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I spent a few hours trying to do this but I keep running in circles and I can't properly fetch data from firebase.

My android app:

- Authenticate users with their email address
- Keep track of how many points each user has (I'm sending their points as a string right now)
- I'm having problems retrieving their points

MY QUESTION IS...

How can I put their already stored points into a textView when the activity is loaded?

Here is what I have
[image]

This is my save function:

```
    private void savePoints(){
    String points = editTextPoints.getText().toString().trim();

    UserPoints userPoints = new UserPoints(points);

    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    final DatabaseReference userRef = databaseReference.child(user.getUid());

    userRef.setValue(userPoints);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Points Saved...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

this is my UserPoints class:

```
public class UserPoints {
public String points;

public UserPoints(String points) {
    this.points = points;
}

public UserPoints(){ }

}
```

Now... any suggestion on how to build a loadPoints so the user can see how many points he has?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you're attaching your listener to the wrong location:

```
private void savePoints(){
    //editTextPoints is my editText field
    String points = editTextPoints.getText().toString().trim();

    UserPoints userPoints = new UserPoints(points);

    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    final DatabaseReference userRef = databaseReference.child(user.getUid());

    userRef.setValue(points);

    userRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            retrievePoints.setText(value);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException(); // don't just ignore errors
        }
    });
}
```

I'd expect that you attach the listener somewhere else btw. Right now it's just going to pick up the same value that you just wrote, so you might as well simply directly set the points to the text view without a listener:

```
retrievePoints.setText(points);
```

Comment: Hello Frank, I was trying to grab the same value for learning purposes. 

You are amazing... I've been sick and not thinking clearly, but you solved my problem in minutes. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: I uploaded the question to get more specific now on how to retrieve already stored data.